# swagger-codegen swift4 codable protocol

Tags: ios, swift, swagger, swift4, swagger-codegen

I'm using `Swagger-codegen(3.0.8)` to generate models from Sales force API and when I run the command

```
 swagger-codegen generate -i Swagger.json -l swift4 --model-name-prefix SFCC
```

the generated models doesn't contains the methods :

```
init(from decoder: Decoder)

func encode(to encoder: Encoder)
```

And I'm wondering if there is param to add to generate them.

yml model example:

```
baskets_result:
    description: Result document containing an array of baskets.
    properties:
      baskets:
        description: The list of baskets for a customer.
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/basket'
        type: array
      total:
        description: The total number of baskets.
        format: int32
        type: integer
```

The generated model:

```
//
// SFCCBasketsResult.swift
//
// Generated by swagger-codegen
// https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen
//

import Foundation

/** Result document containing an array of baskets. */
public struct SFCCBasketsResult: Codable {

    /** The list of baskets for a customer. */
    public var baskets: [SFCCBasket]?

    /** The total number of baskets. */
    public var total: Int?

    public init(baskets: [SFCCBasket]?, total: Int?) { 
        self.baskets = baskets
        self.total = total
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add a link to the Salesforce API definition file (YAML/JSON). Also, do all models have this issue or just specific models?

Comment: Hello i edited the question, thanks in advance.

Comment: i have this in all the models